# Extend Model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, extend

I'm trying to extend a model in rails.

Model `User` uses table `users` in database with field `:username`, `:password`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Model SuperUser uses table `super_users` in database with fields `:user_id`, `:name`:

```
class SuperUser < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end
```

I would like the `SuperUser` to be an extension of `User` so as to be able to do this :

```
SuperUser.create(:name => "foo", :username => "bar", :password => "foobar")
```

or when I fetch data to get something like this

```
> s = SuperUser.find 1
> s.username
> "bar"
```

Has anyone any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 6):

You need to consider two possible patterns of extending your models. One of them, **Single Table Inheritance** is built into Rails and is [well documented](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html). The other pattern, the **Multi Table Inheritance**, which is surprisingly less welcomed in Rails. You need to implement it yourself or use less [popular gem](https://github.com/hzamani/active_record-acts_as) for it.

One of the reasons why, I think, MTI is not well supported in Rails is related to performance. For example, even simple `User.find 1` should be a lookup in two tables.

What you ask in your question (having two tables) is MTI. But why not STI in this simple case? Are `User` and `SuperUser` as deviated from each other that you worry about saving space and using two separate tables for them?

For me it looks like going with a single `users` table, and adding `type` column to it.

```
add_column :users, :type, :string
```

Now:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class SuperUser < User
end
```

and it just works.

Comment: Thank very much for your answer @dimakura, I don't use STI because I want SuperUser to have more attributes than User.

Comment: You can have more attributes for SU with STI @skalogirou

Comment: @skalogirou how did you end up handling this?  Just curious.  Also what other types of attributes?

Answer (score 4):

You'd want to use either **Single Table Inheritance** (STI) or **Multiple Table Inheritance** (MTI). This is not as complicated as it may seem at first. You can read about it [here](http://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-10-multiple-table-inheritance/)